# Navigating to a different tab in navigation subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In an ms access 2010 database, I have a listbox whose afterupdate procedure needs (among other things) to navigate to a specific tab in a navigation subform.  I can get it to change the SourceObject property of the navigation subform, but the selected tab does not get changed, so the user ends up seeing the right source object with the wrong tab selected.  This looks unprofessional.  How can I change both the selected tab and the source object?

I uploaded a simplified database that recreates the problem to [this file sharing site](http://jmp.sh/b/foOShGvTmizzBb6L7vS3).

The list box that needs its afterupdate method changed is called `lstbxClients`. Here is my current draft of its afterupdate method, which is currently throwing an error:

```
Private Sub lstbxClients_AfterUpdate()
  Dim rst
  Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
  rst.FindFirst "ClientNumber = " & lstbxClients.Column(0)
  Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
  'Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform.SourceObject = "qryListCommunicationForms"
  DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "qryListCommunicationForms", "Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform"
  Form.NavigationSubform "  "
  'Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform.SelectedTab = "CommFormsNavBtn"
  Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

How do I change the code above so that it changes both the selected tab AND the source object of the navigation subform when the user clicks on a different record in the listbox?

Comment: My apologies - I was looking at two questions, and typed the answer for the other one into yours.  It actually **was** a C to C# question. I have deleted my answer, but if you  actually saw something worthwhile in it post here and I will restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access gave a relatively decent explanation of what the proper syntax of the path is.

[image: Path argument is of the form: MainForm1.Subform1>Form1.Subform1]

So your BrowseTo command should look like this:

`DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "qryListCommunicationForms", "Main.NavigationSubform>FindClientsNavigation.NavigationSubform"`

Comment: Thank you for this. +1 and credit for the answer.  I am trying to award the bounty to you, but I cannot see how to do so.  S.O. seems to have taken away the bounty functionality from my interface. If there is a way for me to award the bounty to you, I would be happy to do so.  You can use this comment in any communications with them.  They already took the points out of my account.

Answer (score 1):

Use the syntax below

```
DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "qryListCommunicationForms", "Main.NavigationSubform>findClientsNavigation.NavigationSubform", "ClientNumber = " & lstbxClients.Column(0)
```

and

```
DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "ListAddresses", "Main.NavigationSubform>findClientsNavigation.NavigationSubform", "ClientNumber = " & lstbxClients.Column(0)
```

The only change is the second parameter syntax , use

`"Main.NavigationSubform>findClientsNavigation.NavigationSubform"`

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem I noticed with that strategy is that the correct navigation button is not highlighted when you simply change the SourceObject.  I couldn't find a way to modify the SelectedValue of the navigation control, but the BrowseTo command seems to take care of all of that.

Comment: @ThinkingCap +1 for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it :

```
Form_NavFormName.NavigationSubform.SourceObject = "FormName"
```