# Opening subform within navigations (ELI5)

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have an access database I'm building (i've posted occasionally with my questions) and I have a general question about ms access:

How do you open a subform within a navigation form?

I have a master/child tree that is:

`Main Navigation Form
     -> Main Student Records Navigation Form
        -> View All Students Datasheet
        -> View Edit Student`

My goal is to click on the ID of a record in the datasheet, and have it open the "view/edit student" that displays the full details (the datasheet only has a few elements to it).

But I honestly don't understand how to call a subform to open like that. I've read about it, and I thought it'd be something like

`DoCmd.OpenForm Forms!NavigationForm.StudentNav_Form.ViewEditStud_Form`

But this doesn't work. But this problem I'm having I feel like is systemic to the way access works. I'm not sure I understand how referencing and calling objects within VBA works. Reading the msdn articles is only confusing me more >.<

Thanks all!

---

EDIT: I found this: [navigating to a different tab in navigation subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366387/navigating-to-a-different-tab-in-navigation-subform?rq=1)

The `BrowseTo` command seems like what I want, but I'm not sure I understand how to write the syntax to move to the right page... I'm going to experiment but if anyone has any idea I'd love to know!

Comment: So ViewAllStudents is a subform within Student, and is visible on the parent form load?  It sounds like you just need to change ViewAllStudent's recordsource.  - - you can add a _Click event to the form they're clicking on (If they're clicking on the ID field in the Students form, add a Sub called ID_Click to the Students code).  By the time that code is running, ID.Value will hold the value they clicked on.  Then you can change the recordsource of ViewAllStudents to show records of that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, form navigation was one of the hardest things for me to get used to when I started programming in access.  I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName", acNormal, "", "[Record_ID] = " & Me.Record_ID, , acNormal
```

If your Record_ID is for some reason a string it would be with single quotes like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName", acNormal, "", "[Record_ID] = '" & Me.Record_ID & "'", , acNormal
```

Obviously you will need to replace FormName with the name of the form you want to open, and Record_ID with the actual name of that column. By the looks of it your FormName is likely ViewEditStud_Form.

Comment: So I get all that, but just entering in the form name opens up a new window. I'd like it to be that when a user clicks on a record, they click on that from the "View All Students" datasheet (a child of the student nav, which is a child of overall nav), and it opens up the record in the "view/edit student" (once again, child of student nav, child of overall nav). How can I direct the navigation that way?

Comment: Personally I would recommend setting the "Display as Hyperlink" property on one of your fields to "Screen Only" then go to the on click event for that field and put in the code I posted.  Basically then when the user clicks on say the Student name, it will run that code and open to the second form which would be set to the student that the user had clicked on.

Comment: Well that's what I had originally but it's not opening in the navigation pane. It opens as a new window, do you see what I'm saying? Getting the record to open on click isn't the problem, it's the directing the form to then open within the navigation form that is already open. Remember, the datasheet is a child of the student nav and I'd like the view/edit to open as a child of student nav too.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. I didn't want `DoCmd.Open` I wanted `DoCmd.Browseto` as described in the post above. The syntax for the browse to looks like:

```
DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "ViewEditStud_Form", "NavigationForm.NavigationSubform>StudentNav_Form.NavigationSubform"
```

It took me a while to understand this so I'm going to break it down.

`acBrowseToForm` tells it that I'm browsing to a form (obviously!)
`"ViewEditStud_Form"` is the form that I'm browsing to.
`"NavigationForm.NavigationSubform>StudentNav_Form.NavigationSubform"` is the instructions of where to open it. `NavigationForm` is the name of my main navigation form. `.NavigationSubform>` identifies that there is a subform to open it in, and that subform is `StudentNav_Form` which holds a navigation subform (and the end of that indicates that that subform is where the form is to be opened in!)

Hope this helps anyone else!