# Access Navigation Control BrowseTo "The command or action 'BrowseTo' isn't available now. Error 2046

Tags: ms-access, vba

Using MSAccess 2016 64 bit with SQL SERVER Express 2014 backend.

I have a form "frm_Navigation" with a subform control "NavigationSubform" and a Navigation control.

There are several forms for different tasks within the database that are loaded into the NavigationSubform by clicking the buttons on the Navigation control.

Some of the navigation is managed from the Navigation Control, but some is initiated from a subform. When the user clicks a button on the control, it appears "pressed", but when I navigate using the following, I am not able to make the button appear pressed without changing the colour on the button.

This is how I am currently navigation from a subform:

```
    Form_frm_Navigation.NavigationSubform.SourceObject = "frm_SearchResults"
    Form_frm_Navigation.lbl_Header.Caption = "Search Results"
```

I have read the following posts, but sadly I'm not able to accomplish what I am trying to do

https://blogs.office.com/2010/02/23/access-2010-browseto-docmd-and-macro-action/

http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1986422

[navigating to a different tab in navigation subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366387/navigating-to-a-different-tab-in-navigation-subform)

[Opening subform within navigations (ELI5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221186/opening-subform-within-navigations-eli5?lq=1)

Main form: frm_Navigation

subform Control on Main from: NavigationSubform

Subform containing code: frm_Search

Form I am trying to open: frm_SearchResults

```
    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_SearchResults", "frm_Navigation.NavigationSubform"
```

Error '2046': The command or action "BrowseTo" isn't available now.

Expected outcome: frm_Search is loaded in the subform control of frm_Navigation by default. After the user enters criteria in the search fields on the frm_Search and clicks btn_search the results are populated into a table, then the frm_SearchResults is opened to display the found records.

I have tried setting the focus to the Main form first, clearing the source of the NavigationSubform, setting the source of the NavigationSubform to the form I am trying to open (I read somewhere that the form must be open) and several permutations of the BrowseTo arguments.

**EDIT 2016-07-04 16:04 GMT**

It works now as long as the Navigation form is first closed, then reopened. It is not elegant, but the Navigation button now lights up to indicate which is "selected".

Excerpt of code in "frm_Search", a subform of "frm_Navigation" occupying the "frm_Navigation.NavigationSubform"

Is there a way to achieve this without closing the navigation form?

```
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Navigation"
DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_SearchResults", "frm_Navigation.NavigationSubform"
```

Comment: Did you close the frm_Search before trying to navigate to another subform?

Comment: @random_answer_guy Not explicitly as the Search form occupies the NavigationSubform. I have tried clearing the Subform source `Form_frm_Navigation.NavigationSubform.SourceObject = ""`  Followed by `DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_SearchResults", "frm_Navigation.NavigationSubform"` and still get the 2046 error.

Comment: So perhaps it is an error with the query populating the table? The code you just listed: Form_frm_Navigation.NavigationSubform.SourceObject = "" Followed by DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frm_SearchResults", "frm_Navigation.NavigationSubform" is exactly the code I use and it works

Comment: @random_answer_guy It is not impossible, but would be odd because I can set the Subform.SourceObject to the frm_SearchResults and see my data

Comment: @random_answer_guy I can make it work by closing the Navigation form first. I'm not keen on it, but the navigation buttons at least change to show which has been selected. It is marginally better than changing the button colour in VBA.