# Change navigation tab on "Navigation Control" of Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, navigation, controls

Here's my doubt, I have an Navigation Control called "navControl" that haves three tabs("Venda", "Metalização", "Injeção"), and I have one Check Box with three options, I need to change tab according the selected option.

I think I need to use DoCmd.BrowseTo, but don't know how :/

Someone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the *Navigation Target Name* to the name of the form each navigation tab opens in Properties/Data tab of the navigation control..

```
Private Sub YourOptionGroup_Click()
    With Me
        Select Case .YourOptionGroup.Value
            Case 1:
                DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "Form1", "YourMainFormName.NavigationSubform"
            Case 2:
                DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "Form2", "YourMainFormName.NavigationSubform"
            Case 3:
                DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "Form3", "YourMainFormName.NavigationSubform"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not using TabControl, I'm using NavigationControl, do you have any idea?

Comment: Oh I see. So you need to change the subform object according the opton selected?

Comment: Exactly, you know how?

Comment: Ok, that work... But not 100%, the tab that have focus, still wrong, that just change the content from actual tab

Comment: Just set the `SetFocus` property of the navigation button. See answer.

Comment: Almost, it set the focus, but do not "Click"

Comment: Not too sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you have an event procedure behind each navigation button?

Comment: Nop, the navigation buttons just change the tab, in each tab I have differents SubForms, the CheckBox is feeded automatically from database, so when CheckBox is feeded, it have to automatically change the tab, I know, I can use the TabControl, but I'm trying to learn how to use NavigationControl

Comment: You need to handle the 'Click' manually in code like shown above. It wont change automatically as no event is fired when the checkbox value changes programmatically (e.g. from the database).

Comment: my doubt is the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366387/navigating-to-a-different-tab-in-navigation-subform
But I'm not able to adapt the code, can help me?

Comment: Sorry the late, but isn't working, what is the Form1?
My situation is, I have the main form called "frmOP", inside this, i have the navigation control called "navControl", one of his buttons is "btNavVenda", that opens the subForm "frmSubMetaisOPVenda", how would my code look?

Comment: Change `Form1`, `Form2`, `Form3` to the names of the subforms you want to load e.g. `frmSubMetaisOPVenda`.

Comment: the "NavigationSubform" is the same as Form1?