# How to navigate from a form to a subform in a different form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, subform

I'm working on a Access-Database that is split into multiple parts. Each has a Main-Form with Subforms in nested Tabs.

> Walkthrough

We have a starting-Area that is separated into different Themes. Those theme-forms have buttons that represent Subthemes.

[image: The starting Form in Theme 2]

When I hit Button A i want to navigate from Mainform 1 to Mainform 2 Subtheme A (easy as it is the default).

When I hit Button B I want to navigate from Mainform 1 to Mainform 2 Subtheme B. (I can't get this to work)

[image: Main Form 2 - SubTheme2 opened per default on Subform A]

> What i know

I can easily get from Mainform 1 to Mainform 2 landing per default on Theme 1

```
Private Sub buttonB_Click()
   DoCmd.openForm "Mainform2", _
End Sub
```

I don't know how to navigate to Mainform2->Sub Theme B. I can open the right subform using the OpenArgs but i cant do it with the Tabs. I tried to use the DoCmd.browseTo in onLoad() of mainform2 but that breaks the process.

If i am not mistaken there should be a way to use DoCmd.browseTo in the buttonB_click() but i cant get the path right.

[DoCmd.OpenForm Method (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/ff820845.aspx)

[DoCmd.BrowseTo Method (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/ff196381.aspx)

I tried to describe the problem as general as possible so answers can be helpful for others as well. I hope you can help me!

Comment: Are you navigating using a tab control or a navigation control?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529082/change-navigation-tab-on-navigation-control-of-access/44529794#44529794

Comment: I believe the implementation i use is NavigationControl.  The example from Kostas is on tab control and doesnt work.

Comment: For people looking this up: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff821707.aspx Navigation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff844930.aspx TabControl

Comment: I will rework my question later, lets see if i can make it a bit more detailed

Comment: @KostasK. maybe i can work it out with your SetFocus comment from the post you linked. I'll get back here when i have worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to resolve it:

First we navigate to the Main-Form of Theme2 and tell it which topic we want with the help of OpenArgs:

```
Private Sub buttonThemeB_Click()
   DoCmd.openForm "Mainform2", _
   OpenArgs:="Theme B"
End Sub
```

In the FormLoad() of Mainform2 we check the OpenArgs and navigate the Subform-Controle:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

   Dim strSubFormToken As String

   ' If OpenArgs property contains a subform name, open corresponding subform  
  If Me.OpenArgs <> 0 Then strSubFormToken = Me.OpenArgs

  Select Case strSubFormToken
     Case "Theme A"
        strSubForm = "form_themeA"
     Case "Theme B"
        strSubForm = "form_themeB"
  End Select

  strSubForm =     
  If Len(strSubForm) > 0 Then
     DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, strSubForm, "frmTheme2.Navigationsunterformular" 'Your Navigationtarget
  End If

End Sub
```

The Mainproblem in all this is that if you use the *DoCmd.BrowseTo Path to Subform Control* you have to know some rules that aren't documented:

> the “>” character seems unusual, that’s because it has been introduced specifically for the Path parameter of BrowseTo. Its meaning is this: The form to the right of the “>” character is loaded into the subform control specified to its left.

- The path must specify a series of Form.SubFormControl pairs. Each subform control specified must be a control in the form that precedes it in the path.
- The pairs must be separated by the “>” character. 
  and most important:
- **The first form in the path must be the form that is currently loaded directly in the Access window** (or browser window if the application is running on the web.) This means that the Path parameter only allows you to change the contents of a currently-visible subform control.

So we have to first open the new main-form before navigating the navigation-subcontrol.

Seems to be the best way to handle this.
Thanks for the suggestions!